# JavaScript: Assign an object to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign the local var `UgcItems` to `uploadedItems` but when I try to return the value I get `undefined`.  If I put the `console.log` inside of the `.getJSON` then I get the appropriate value.  The problem with that is that the scope is inside of the function.  What can I do to get the JSON out of the function?

```
$(function(){
    var uploadedItems;
    $.getJSON("GetExistingUgcItems?workItemId=1", function (UgcItems) {
        uploadedItems = UgcItems;
    });

    console.log(uploadedItems);
});
```

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: One doesn't "assign objects to objects". Only *variables and properties* can be "assigned to"; neither of which are objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is that `getJSON` executes asynchronously by default.  So the assignment to `uploadedItems` happens after the `console.log(uploadedItems)` command completes.

Instead of defining `uploadedItems` in the root function, define a method which takes `uploadedItems`.  Put all of the code which uses `uploadedItems` in this function and call it from the completed handler

```
var withUploadedItems = function(uploadedItems) {
  console.log(uploadedItems);
  // etc ...
};

$.getJSON("GetExistingUgcItems?workItemId=1", function (UgcItems) {
  uploadedItems = fromJSON(toJSON(UgcItems));
  withUploadedItems(uploadedItems);
});
```

Comment: Dang it!  This has bit me in the butt in other languages before.  Thank you for your help!!